# MySQL server keeps going away even after wait_timeout set to a year

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine

I've got a Cloud SQL server instance running through Google App Engine and the MySQL server keeps going away. This was never an issue before but for some reason it has just decided to rear its ugly head.

In the server-side script I set the wait_timeout to 31536000.

I also created a wait_timeout flag in the Dev Console of GAE.

Still this issue crops up, and it does so very inconsistently, sometimes working for a day or two, then dropping off the face of the planet. I redeploy the script and then it works for an hour, and then goes away. It makes no sense to me.

Has anyone had this happen to them before?

The first error I get is this:

```
OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

Then:

```
OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

If I were to have one theory it would be that, on the client side, a function was being called to the mysql server and then the client called another function before the MySQL server had finished the first, and this somehow screwed it up?

I have no idea.

Comment: Can you please share the error you are getting?

Comment: The first error I get is this:

OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
Then:

OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

Comment: Set Variable max_allowed_packet to 32M or high in mysql config to get rid of this error.

Comment: hmm okay i'll give it a shot. thank you. for future reference, could you explain why this might work? What is going on by doing that?

Comment: when you send a query to the server that is incorrect or too large. If mysqld receives a packet that is too large or out of order, it assumes that something has gone wrong with the client and closes the connection. If you need big queries (for example, if you are working with big BLOB columns), you can increase the query limit by setting the server's max_allowed_packet variable, which has a default value of 1MB. You may also need to increase the maximum packet size on the client end